# h2o GAM Index out of bounds

Tags: r, h2o, gam

I recently updated the h2o version from `3.32.0.3` to `3.32.0.4`, and many codes that used to work do not work anymore.
More specifically, every time that I try to fit a `gam` model I always get the same error.

```
Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321: 'Index -1 out of bounds for length 7', caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 7
```

Here the step to reproduce the error:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(h2o)

h2o.init()

mtcars_h2o <- as.h2o(mtcars)

att_model <- h2o.gam(y = "mpg",
                     gam_columns = c("disp", "hp", "drat", "wt"),
                     family = "gamma",
                     link = "log",
                     training_frame = mtcars_h2o,
                     nfold = 3,
                     standardize = TRUE,
                     alpha = .5,
                     lambda_search = TRUE,
                     model_id = "GAM_Model")
```

And the h2o version

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
     H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 630 milliseconds 
     H2O cluster timezone:       America/Chicago 
     H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
     H2O cluster version:        3.32.0.4 
     H2O cluster version age:    4 days  
     H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_marco_xbw859 
     H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
     H2O cluster total memory:   3.85 GB 
     H2O cluster total cores:    8 
     H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
     H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
     H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
     H2O Connection port:        54321 
     H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
     H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
     H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4 
     R Version:                  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
```

Is there a bug in the actual package, considering this version is fairly or am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: I just tested your code on latest H2O 3.32.1.1 and had no issue. Try installing a fresh new R env and see if it is reproducible.

Comment: After updating h2o everything works. Thank you